# Google Map API 3: dynamic circle with zoom level

Tags: google-maps

In google maps v3, it is possible to have a dynamic circle that based on the zoom level, for example, in zoom level 1, the radius of circle is 5m, while in zoom level, the radius become 20m?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i get this right you have to do it manually.[Create a circle](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Circle) in the body of the [zoom_change() event of the map](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) everytime the user changes the zoom.The radius of the circle depends on the logic of your application